# WordPress : a page link in <a> Not working

Tags: wordpress, href

I'm trying to make a page link like below but it's not working.
(I'm new developer in WP).

```
<a href="<?= home_url() ?>/about-us">about us</a>
```

Comment: Any error you get? explain more so we can help you

Comment: Try this <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/about-us">about us</a>

Comment: thanks man. I'm trying

Comment: need more information...because you havent tagged php i'm assuming you are inserting this into the content editor...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your code with this

```
<a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/about-us">about us</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/about-us">about us</a>
```

Comment: This is same thing .

Answer (score 3):

```
<a href="<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>/about-us">about us</a>
```

Would you please check above code?

Answer (score 2):

just add a echi before home_url()
/about-us">about us